# Why do I get AccessControlException: access denied when I add BouncyCastleProvider to Security in Tomcat servlet

Tags: java, security, tomcat, servlets, bouncycastle

I've created a Java servlet and runs it in a Tomcat server on a web hotel. It should send push messages to iOS devices so I added JavaPNS. This works fine in my local Tomcat server, but when I deploy it on the Tomcat server provided by a web hotel then this statement:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

gives the Exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-193" java.lang.InternalError: cannot create instance of org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.symmetric.AES$Mappings : java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.security.SecurityPermission putProviderProperty.BC) 
at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.loadAlgorithms(Unknown Source) 
at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.setup(Unknown Source) 
at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.access$000(Unknown Source) 
at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider$1.run(Unknown Source) 
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.(Unknown Source) 
at javapns.communication.ConnectionToAppleServer.(ConnectionToAppleServer.java:41) 
....
```

Probably the web hotel have some sort of security turned on in the Tomcat server that I don't have turned on locally.

Does anyone know if there any work-around to this problem?
If not, what should I ask the support at the web hotel to change to make this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Don't attempt to install BouncyCastle as a provider. Create a new `BouncyCastle` instance in your application, and pass that provider to the `getInstance()` overload that accepts a `Provider` parameter on each of the cryptographic services.

Modifications to the `Security` class affect all applications in the container; they aren't local to your application. Use a more targeted approach that doesn't require global changes.

Relying on an installed provider can be convenient in a standalone application, but it creates a lot of problems in the long run, when you require a specific provider, and a library written on top of the JCA doesn't allow you to specify a provider.

Comment: Thank you. when trying to implement your suggestion I came to the strange conclusion that BouncyCastle is not needed in JavaPNS. So then I just removed setting the BouncyCastleProvider as a security provider and now it works just fine!

Comment: Could you show us some sample code for the instructions in the first paragraph?

Answer (score 1):

There is no work-around. There are a number of possibilities. Explain to your provider what you want to do and discuss the options with them. They include:

- The provider installing the BouncyCastle provider
- The provider granting you the necessary permissions to add the provider yourself

Note that if you have a shared Tomcat instance then the chances of the provider agreeing to any of the above are pretty slim.